# Getting C# Object Property Values with jQuery JSON

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

So I have this:

```
{"d":[{"__type":"Like","Id":345,"Sender":"JohnSmith","SourceId":338,"DateTime":"\/Date(1321057654000)\/","FromStream":true}]}
```

And this:

```
        function LikesSuccess(result, userContext, methodName) {
            for (var key in result) {
                alert(key.Sender);
            }
        }
```

JSON returns an array of type "Like" with the properties shown above.
Is there another way of getting "JohnSmith" from Sender? Because this returns undefined.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.d.length; i++) {
    alert(result.d[i].Sender);
}
```

because your JSON object has the key `d`.  >> [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PR9bF/)

Comment: Yes, this resolves the issue. One question, where did that "d" come from? Does ASP.NET automatically assign it? I did not specify it anywhere in my ScriptMethod.

Comment: It was a change added with .NET 3.5 for security reasons. See http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/

Comment: @user1027620: Check out [this article from Encosia](http://encosia.com/a-breaking-change-between-versions-of-aspnet-ajax/) about the security reasons behind Microsoft's encapsulation of return objects under the d property.

Answer (score 0):

use jquery

var obj = $.parseJSON(str)

Then you get the js object

Comment: His example is already an object, not a string which needs to be parsed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
function LikesSuccess(result, userContext, methodName) {
            for (var property in result.Properties) {
                alert(result[property]);
            }
        }
```

I remember having used something similar, when I was working with Asp.Net Ajax, web services. Not sure about the correct syntax though.